# Adding a custom Emoji (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, emoji

Code:

```
...
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'e_lastprism' in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name = ('lastprism'), image = (b'D:\Desktop\diskord BOT\emoji\lastprism.jpg'))
...
```

After entering, an error emerges:
`discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Unsupported image type given`

Full Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 251, in on_message
    await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name = ("lastprism"), image = (b'D:\Desktop\diskord BOT\emoji\lastprism.jpg'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1504, in create_custom_emoji
    img = utils._bytes_to_base64_data(image)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 299, in _bytes_to_base64_data
    mime = _get_mime_type_for_image(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 295, in _get_mime_type_for_image
    raise InvalidArgument('Unsupported image type given')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Unsupported image type given
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not came across this one before but try using `.jpg` or `.jpeg`. as it says the wrong image type.

Comment: I converted the file to jpg, but the problem persists and the same error is returned

Comment: You could also use an image by uploading it via [this link.](https://ss.2mpcraft.xyz/)

Comment: * . Jpeg doesn't work either.
Here is an image(PS.it is inserted into the discord via the server settings):
https://ss.2mpcraft.xyz/g0IJbWdj

Comment: Try uploading it via [this link](https://ss.2mpcraft.xyz). As I said ^^^.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my code with:

```
with open("D:\Desktop\diskord BOT\emoji\lastprism.png", "rb") as img:
    img_byte = img.read()
    await message.guild.create_custom_emoji(name = ("lastprism"), image = img_byte)
```